# Send large canvas data to server

Tags: c#, ajax, canvas, webmethod, todataurl

I have tried sending canvas data as an image but when the image is big it is not sending the data so I tried to send as form data but i am stuck in receiving the code. The codebehind receives as htmlinputelementobject. How can I receive it? Can someone please help.

Html:

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1).toString();
var dataInput = document.createElement("input");
    dataInput.setAttribute("name", "imgdata");
    dataInput.setAttribute("value", data);
    dataInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
    myForm.appendChild(dataInput);
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "HTML5Camera.aspx/Upload",
    type: "POST",
    // data : $('form').serialize(),
    data: "{ 'image': '" + data1 + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert('success')
    }
});
```

CodeBehind:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string Upload(string image)    

    {

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your server to accept larger uploads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the request limit in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" ... />
```

Here 8 mb as an example (the `...` are indicating other information you might have in the file/tag). All base-64 encoded files has a 33% increase in size, something to consider when setting max limit.

(It could possibly be an error when you copied the example into the post, but `data1` is not defined anywhere, ref. the ajax method).

**Update** for completeness (from comments):

```
<system.web.extensions> 
  <scripting> 
    <webServices> 
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/> 
    </webServices>
  </scripting> 
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: In addition to your suggestion increasing the json serialization limit also fixed the issue as shown below

Comment: Code : system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code to increase json serialization in web.config

Code:

```
 <system.web.extensions>
 <scripting>
 <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
 </webServices>
 </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>
```